# I have 2 points (x1,y1) & (x2,y2) and a circle, suppose there is a line between the 2 points I need to check if there is collision with the circle

Tags: python, collision-detection, ar.drone

As I mentioned in the title, suppose I have a line segment from point 1 to point 2 and there is a circle with a center and radius I need to check if there is going to be a collision with the circle using code. This is how far I got.
However, there is an issue with closestX and closestY since I need to check if they are on the line segment from point 1 to point 2 because if they are not on the line segment then there will be No collision. Sadly though Im stuck here and I cannot figure out a way to check if they are on the line segment or not. Please help thank you.

```py
import math
p=2
obsHeight=200
DroneHeight=150
cx=3
cy=3
r=1
x1=1
y1=1
x2=1.5
y2=1.5


if DroneHeight<=obsHeight:
    distX= x1 - x2
    distY= y1 - y2
    length=math.sqrt((distX*distX) + (distY*distY ))
    dot= (((cx-x1)*(x2-x1)) + ((cy-y1)*(y2-y1)) )/(math.pow(length,p))
    closestX=x1+( dot * (x2-x1))
    closestY=y1+( dot * (y2-y1))
    print(" Closest x: ",closestX)
    print(" Closest y: ",closestY)
    distX=closestX-cx
    distY= closestY-cy
    distance= math.sqrt((distX*distX) + (distY*distY ))
    print("The distance is: ", distance)
    print("The length is: ", length)
    if (r==distance):
        print("Touching")
    elif (distance<r):
        print("COLLIDING")
    else:
        print("Will not collide")
else:
    print(" Will not collide, the drone is higher than the obstacle")
```

Comment: [edit] and add code as text not as image please

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: First: if both points are inside radius, there can't be a collision. If one is outside and one inside, there must be a collision. The (relatively) hard part is checking if both points outside intersects curvature. Is simple to do if you look up how to find closest distance between line segment and point (center), and compare that to the radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the specificity of your code, let's say that you have a line segment, a center and a radius. Let's write a general solution to whether a line segment in N-dimensions intersects a hyper-sphere in N-dimensions. This will give us the correct solution for your problem in the special case of 2D.

Your function signature would look like this:

```
def intersects(p1, p2, c, r):
```

`p1` and `p2` are vectors of length N. In your case, `p1 = np.array([1, 1])`, and `p2 = np.array([1.5, 1.5])`. `c` is a vector of the same length (`c = np.array([3, 3])`), and `r` is a scalar radius (`r = 1`). I strongly recommend using numpy arrays for your math because it is much faster if you use it right, and you can apply element-wise operations to arrays (e.g. `p2 - p1`) without using a loop.

A line passing through  `p1` and `p2` can be parametrized as `p = p1 + t * (p2 - p1)`. Every point on the line `p` corresponds some value of the parameter `t`. Specifically, `t == 0` corresponds to `p = p1` and `t == 1` corresponds to `p = p2`. That means that you can know if a point is on the line segment by checking if its parameter is in the range `[0, 1]`.

The problem then becomes finding the value of `t` such that `p` is closest to `c`. If `t < 0` or `t > 1`, then you know that the extrema for the line segment are at the endpoints. Otherwise, you need to compare the distances of both the endpoints and the `p` you found.

There are a couple of different ways of coming up with the solution. The geometric approach uses the fact that the nearest approach happens at the perpendicular from `c` to the line. The differential approach finds where the derivative of the length is zero. I will show the former here.

[image]

Looking at the diagram, you have the following equation:

```
(c - p).dot(p2 - p1) == 0
(c - p1 - t * (p2 - p1)).dot(p2 - p1) == 0
(c - p1).dot(p2 - p1) - t * (p2 - p1).dot(p2 - p1) == 0
t == (c - p1).dot(p2 - p1) / (p2 - p1).dot(p2 - p1)
```

You can now write your function like this:

```
def intersects(p1, p2, c, r):
    c1 = np.subtract(c, p1)
    c2 = np.subtract(c, p2)

    dist1 = np.linalg.norm(c1)
    dist2 = np.linalg.norm(c2)

    # If point are on opposite sides of circle, intersects
    if (r - dist1) * (r - dist2) < 0:
        return True

    # If both on inside, does not intersect
    if r > dist1:
        return False

    dp = np.subtract(p2, p1)
    t = dp.dot(c1) / dp.dot(dp)

    # If closest approach is outside segment, does not intersect
    # convince yourself of this (use symmetry about the line c-p)
    if t < 0 or t > 1:
        return False

    cp = np.subtract(p1 + t * dp, c)
    distp = np.linalg.norm(cp)
    # only other possibility of approach is when closest point is inside radius
    return distp <= r
```

---

The problem of finding the distance between a point and a line has cropped up a number of times on Stack Overflow, and in my applications as well, so I recently added it to a library of utilities that I maintain, [`haggis`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). You can build a solution using [`haggis.math.segment_distance`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.math.segment_distance) with very similar logic. I specifically made the function operate in line segment or full-line mode for this purpose:

```
def intersects(p1, p2, c, r):
    dist1 = np.linalg.norm(c1 := np.subtract(c, p1))
    dist2 = np.linalg.norm(c2 := np.subtract(c, p2))
    if (r - dist1) * (r - dist2) < 0: # Opposite sides of circle
        return True
    if r > dist1:                     # Both inside circle
        return False
    d = segment_distance(c, p1, p2)
    return d < r
```

You could rewrite the last two lines as follows:

```
    d, t = segment_distance(c, p1, p2, segment=False, return_t=True)
    return d < r and 0 <= t <= 1
```

Comment: wow thank you so much!! the program works perfectly, however if I put p2 as (4,5) there should be collision since the points are on opposite sides of the circle. The output is incorrect.

Comment: @AbdullahAl-asmari. Interesting. I'll look into it

Comment: Yeah it should go to the first if condition and then return as true however it's not. I really appreciate your help thank you so much.

Comment: @AbdullahAl-asmari. I had a typo in the equations. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you so much, but for instance if I take the center as [3,3] and r=2 and p1 [1,2] and p2[5,5] there should be collision since points are on opposite points of the circle. Somehow its still giving me the output for noncollision and I don't know why :(

Comment: @AbdullahAl-asmari. I will work on in until your example returns correct results. Thanks for catching the error

Comment: You have my thanks. Seriously I appreciate it.

Comment: @AbdullahAl-asmari. There was a typo `t == dp.dot(c1) / dp.dot(dp)` should have been an assignment, not a comparison. You likely had a variable `t` outside the function, which is why you did not catch it as a NameError immediately (I had one too while I was testing). The test case you provided returns True now.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the squared distance of the center of the circle to the line by

```
d2 = ((y1-y2)*(cx-x1)+(x2-x1)*(cy-y1))**2/((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
```

Now just compare that value to the squared radius. If d2<r**2 then the line cuts the circle.

Edit:
I think you already are pretty close to a correct solution. In the line where you calculate the dot product, you should divide by the length of the line segment and not by its squared length. Just putting a (...)**0.5 around the math.pow expression should give the correct value.

Note:
Phython has a builtin power operator called **, so no need to use math.pow

Comment: Except it's a line segment, so you need to know a little more info...

Comment: This still does not solve the issue, look at the points I set, the program should give me an output of No collision since the line is outside of the circle.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes you are right. Considering the code snipped that was provided, I assumed that the OP is looking for an intersection with the infinite line throught the points, but re-reading the question I also think the question is explicitly about line segments

Comment: @AbdullahAl-asmari I suggest you follow the comment of MadPhysicist to your question. You should also make clear if a collision with the circle edge is looked for or a collision with the circle area, as this makes a difference if both endpoints of the line segments are inside the circle.

Comment: I've posted the full solution.